# R-Programming: Chart the Z distribution of a factor's frequency

Tags: r

I have reviewed a number of posts regarding histograms/barcharts from categorical data but I still can't seem to progress. I have a data set of names (single column) and each name occurs anywhere from once to 8,000 times. I can create a table with variable and frequency and I can move that table to a data frame but o matter what I try I can't even get a barplot much less a histogram with variable on x axis and frequency on the y axis.

Ultimately, I want to use the table or dataframe with name and frequency to calculate the Z score for each name and then graph the distribution. I can do this easily with a series of numbers but doing it with a categorical variable has me stumped.
thanks,
rms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
example_data <- data.frame(Name = sample(paste0("Name", 1:15), size = 8000, replace=TRUE, prob = (1:15)/sum(1:15)))

counts <- as.data.frame(table(example_data))
colnames(counts) <- c("Name", "Freq")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = counts, aes(x = Name, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

For future reference, it's a little easier to answer if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), or go into more detail about what you've tried already. Hope this helps!